# Load data into input text form

Tags: jquery

I use this code to load data into my textarea:

```
jQuery('.content_container').load('http://www.evedalsvardshus.se/plugins/calendar/edit_dates.php', {'value': datum} );
```

But when I try to load data into my input text form with this code:

```
jQuery('.header').load('http://www.evedalsvardshus.se/plugins/calendar/get_header.php');
```

Nothing happens. The get_header.php contains only "asdsd".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function tries to set the inner HTML which doesn't work for a text field. You need to set its value instead:

```
$.get('/plugins/calendar/get_header.php', function(result) {
    $('.header').val(result);
});
```

The [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function sends an AJAX request and in the success callback set the value of the text field.